# Confusion as to why there is a force of $2T$ acting on the block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

In the image above, I'm confused as to why there are $2T$ pulling the $20\space kg$ block on the left. $T$ is the tension in the other string. Considering that both are the same string, wouldn't there be a force of just $T$?

Comment: How many "strings" are acting on the 20 kg block?

Comment: Not sure, the exact question is "A 20 kg block with a pulley attached slides along a frictionless ledge. It is connected by a massless string to a 5-kg block via the arrangement as shown. Find the acceleration of each block and the tension in the connecting string." Solution shows that there is a force of 2T on the 20 kg block

Comment: Perhaps this will help? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulley#How_it_works

Comment: Wouldn't the net tension be the sum of T/2 + T/2 then?

Comment: Not if you call the tension in the string $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put gaps in the string.
All you need to do is put in arrowheads to indicate the direction of the tension force $T$ at the end of each string.
The indicated tension force is the force at the end of a string due to the bit of string attached to it.

[image]

You then have free body diagrams which should help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For an intuitive idea of why this is the case, imagine if it was *the sliding block* that was bolted on a wall rather than the surface, and the surface (to which the end of the string is attached) that was movable.

Then the bolted block would have to carry **both** the other free-falling block, as well as this surface attached to the string. Now it suddenly feels very natural that the total force on the bolted block is **larger** than $T$, because $T$ is what the free-falling block pulls with - and the bolted block has more than just the free-falling block to hold back against.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use an equation to model something in real life, you as the human have to do some interpreting to convert letters into concepts.

It seems in this problem, the letter $T$ has been assigned to how much each strand of wire/rope/string is pulling on the block. Because there are two such wires pulling on the block, the *total* force is $T$.

With these ropes, it is also helpful to realize that if there is a force $T$ on one side of a string, it is the same force (in the opposite direction) on the other side of the string. Hence, there is $T$ pulling on the hanging mass, and $T$ pulling on the post.

This problem is a great illustration of how pulleys can be used to amplify the total amount of force (the $2T$ caused by a small force (in this case, the hanging mass)

Answer (score 0):

This has a very simple answer to it. Let the mass of the pulley be $m$ (ideal pulley is massless) and it is moving with acceleration $a$.

Let $T'$ be the tension in the string connecting the pulley to the block of mass $20 kg$ and $T$ be the tension in the string connecting the pulley to the other block and the support.

*Since the strings are massless and inextensible tension is same throughout each string.*

Free body diagram of the pulley :

[image]

On applying Newton's second law on the pulley, we get the following equation of motion,

$ma=2T-T'$ $\tag1$

In most of the questions the default assumption is that the pulleys are massless (or ideal). The pulley in your problem is also ideal unless stated otherwise.

$0.a=2T - T'$

$\therefore \space T'=2T$ $\tag 2$

$T'$ will be twice of $T$ and independent of the pulley's value of acceleration. This way of establishing relation between tensions proves very useful when the pulleys are movable.

Free body diagram of $20kg$ block :

[image]

For the $20kg$ block, equation of motion will be given as,

$20a=T'$

or $20a=2T$ $\tag 3$

***From the equation $(1)$, it also follows that if the pulley had  mass, $T'\neq 2T$.***